# Clear TAGS column specific device in OneSignal

Tags: android, onesignal

I am using from `OneSignal` for send notification .

**Problem:** When I remove app from device should clear `TAGS` column of that device but don't clear `TAGS` column of that device.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you are uninstalling the app?

OneSignal does not delete tags when users uninstall the app, because they may re-install it. If you want to delete tags when the user uninstalls, you can have your backend look at `notification_types`, if the value is -10 then the user has unsubscribed and your backend can make an API call to delete tags for that user.